# Two way relationships with angularfire2 and firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I recently started firebase and I have a bit of experience on Ionic so I decided to developp an App which uses firebase.

I currently have a problem with two way relationships. I have users and groups so users can have multiple groups and groups can have multiple users. I read th doc about those types of database on firebase and build my database as they recommended :

```
groups
--group1
----participants
------user1
------user2
--group2
----participants
------user1
users
--user1
----groups
------group1
------group2
--user2
----groups
------group1
```

I'd like to have the "realtime feature" like when you call

```
db.list('/users')
```

everything is syncing automatically.

Right now I did that

```
this.groupKeySubscription = db.list('/users/' + this.authProvider.getUserId() + '/groups').subscribe(groupKeys => {
  this.groups = [];
  groupKeys.forEach(groupInfo => {
    this.db.object('/groups/' + groupInfo.$key).take(1).subscribe((group) => {
      this.groups.push(group);
    })
  })
});
```

The problem is that everytime data changes, my groups array is cleared and filled so the screen is flickering for like a ms (also I think it's not very efficient).

Is there a way to avoid that ? Or should I just retrieve the data each time it's updated and looping on my array to modify just what's been updated ?

Thanks

Comment: try this approach by mpeguero  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/708

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I think this is the right approach for me, I just don't really understand the part in the view
    {{ (group.data | async)?.field }}
If my user has a field name and description I must put that how ?

Comment: {{(group.data |async)?.name}}

Comment: That's what I tried but It doesn't seem to work
I wrote 
<ion-card *ngFor="let group of groups2 | async">
<ion-card-header>{{(group.data | async)?.name}}</ion-card-header>
</ion-card>

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to mohamad rabee, I ended up using the solution of his link

```
this.groups2 = this.db.list('URLtoGroupKeys').map(groupKeys => {
  return groupKeys.map(key => {
    key.data = this.db.list('URLtoGroup');
    return key
  })
})
```

and in the view

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let group of groups2 | async" (press)="presentActionSheet(group)" (click)="setCurrentGroup(group)" [ngClass]="{'active': group==currentGroup}">
  <ion-card-header *ngFor="let data of group.data | async | slice:1:2">{{data.$value}}</ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content *ngFor="let data of group.data | async | slice:0:1">{{data.$value}}</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

The use of the slice pipe is, for me, not the most beautifulsolution but it's working quite good

The only problem is that I don't quite understand thos five line in the .ts file ...
I get the db.list() part, the map is like a foreach or is it superior (with more feature) ?

Comment: with map you can manipulate the data  before subscribe, for example if you have an array in the db and you want to subscribe just to the size of this array, you can return the array size within the map and then you can subscribe to the size, `db.list('url').map(array => {return array.length}).subscribe(size=>{/* do with size what you want */})`

Comment: Thank you very much fro the explanation, I replaced the secon db.list with a db.object so that I just have an observable and I than can call ?.field
My understading of map is quite better now